# Echo pictures based on ID

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a products page with full of product pictures with unique id from database for every product. When i click the product, it directs me to another page with unique id for each product. I need the page to show pictures based on the unique id of the product.

The page to click the product CODE:

```
<a href="productdetails.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
<img src="images/<?php echo $row["image"]; ?>" class="img-responsive" />
</a>
```

I need the clicked product page to show pictures based on the unique id.
CODE:

```
<?php
 $getimagefrom = "SELECT image FROM product_details_image WHERE imagecode = 1 ORDER BY id";
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $getimagefrom);
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
?>
  <img class="imgStyle" src="images/<?php echo $row["image"]; ?>" /> 

<?php
        }
?>
```

The ORDER BY id is unique code that should be called when the product with the unique code is clicked.However, whenever i click the product, it goes to the page with unique id but the product shown is the same id always.

May ask question if not clear of it.

Comment: Post your original SELECT query

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product ORDER BY id ASC";

Comment: @YashParekh i select all product from table with auto increment id. So the product shows from id 1, 2, 3 and so on

Comment: As far as I understand, You want to pass a `product id` and based on that get the image id from `product_details_image` table. Am I right??
Or anything else

Comment: yes, to be more in details, when i click product id 1, it goes to another page and shows several pictures of product id 1, when click product id 2 it goes to another page and shows several pictures of product id 2. there are 5 images with same id, which is 1, but different imagecode which is 1,2,3,4,5.